# CSS Background COVER property doesnt works on Phone

Tags: android, html, css, browser

I'm experiencing a strange issue: When I open a website on my `Android` 4.1 phone (default browser), the background image doesnt cover the background as it should.

Here is the screen from phone:

[image: Screenshot from phone running browser]

Pieces of code, according to background attributes:

```
...
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
...
background: #fff url('img/main_bg.png')no-repeat center center;
-webkit-background-size: cover !important;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='img/main_bg.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='img/main_bg.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

Although, things that I've tried is setting the min-hegith and width property at 100 % - didnt make the things work.

Hope that you have any ideas, how to figure out this issue.

Comment: On your computer it works fine?

Comment: Yes, I'm experiencing the problem only on my Android phone. All browsers on PC displays it correctly (covers all the background with the image).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code snippet. It seems to be a problem of the native `Android` browser to parse multiple `CSS` tags for the background property. So define each property seperate might help:

```
...
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
...
background-image:url('img/main_bg.png');
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: cover !important;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='img/main_bg.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='img/main_bg.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

Comment: Well, the final solution was to create a separate <div> element (on same hierarchy level) with "fixed" css property, 100% w and h. Element has no childs, so the background is displayed correctly now.

Comment: But that does not explain, why it runs on all browser except the native Android browsers

Comment: Yes, it wasnt the final problem fix, I just posted a possible solution, like fix with a tape. 
Anyway, if anything usefull would be done to that web design, I'm gona post it here. 
Thanks for all the help you provided. Good Luck.