# Website background displaying incorrectly on Android. Chrome DevTools not reflecting this

Tags: android, html, css, mobile, media-queries

I launched a very simple splash page about a month ago. I designed the website trying to make sure that mobile users will see the website correctly. I used Chrome Dev tools and a few other online tools to make sure the website displays correctly on mobile.

The other day, however, a few of my android friends sent me a screenshot of my website. The background is not filling in as it is supposed to. This only happens on Android and for the life of me I can't figure out why. In all of my tools it appears fine which is making this very difficult to troubleshoot. When I preview as an Android phone such as a Galaxy S4 in the ChromeDev tools the background is shown correctly. Any ideas?

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,800,900);
html {
  background: url('./freedom.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  background: rgba(247, 247, 247, 1);
}
container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='./freedom.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='./freedom.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
headline {
  font-size: 400%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #0A83FF;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: -7px;
}
description {
  padding-left: 2%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
}
icons {
  font-size: 225%;
}
a {
  color: #000000;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #0A83FF;
}
red:hover {
  color: #FF0000;
}
green:hover {
  color: #00BC00;
}
yellow:hover {
  color: #E5E500;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 574px) {
  headline {
    font-size: 200%;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #0A83FF;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: -3px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://normalize-css.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <title>blah.com</title>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.gif">
  </head>
  <body>
    <container>
      <headline>Blah</headline>
      <description>
        <red>Hi</red>,
        <green>There</green>,
        <yellow>Friends</yellow>.
        <icons>
          <p>
            <a href="http://www.github.com/blah" target="new"><i class="fa fa-github-square"></i></a>
            <a href="http://www.twitter.com/blah" target="new"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=308920572" target="new"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i></a>
          </p>
        </icons>
      </description>
    </container>
  </body>

</html>
```

It's like the background is scaling in width, but not adjusting for height. And why would this just be happening on Android? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: which browser are you using on android? Chrome?

Comment: This sounds similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295082/css-background-cover-property-doesnt-works-on-phone

Comment: @LearningCODE - Yes, they are using Chrome on Android

Comment: try using `max-width` and `max-height`

Comment: try using `crop` instead of `scale` in `sizingMethod` if the above doesn't work..

Comment: @LearningCODE - Thank you. I just made some changes. I have an iPhone, no android present, and since my dev tools aren't helping I'll have to wait until tomorrow to ask an android friend to check out to see if it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `min-height: 100%;` to `html` selector with background. It will sure work!

```
html {
  background: url('./texas.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Worked like a charm!